# R survival analysis: coxph - Including individuals with time zero

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I have a theoretical problem and was wondering if someone could explain this to me. 
I am currently using the command *coxph* in R to perform survival analysis on my dataset. However, I came across an issue on how R handles failure times of zero.

In my dataset I have patients with a follow up time of zero (t=0) and noticed that the R command *coxph* does not exclude these patients when performing a cox proportional hazard model. These patients are included in the risk set from the start and seem to be contributing to the output of this model. Furthermore, when excluding these patients and subsequently performing a cox PH model returns different results in beta coefficients.

I am curious in to why these individuals are included and how the *coxph* command performs this type of analysis when t=0 and was wondering if anyone could clarify this.

I tried it with a small test dataset and got two different results.

```
id <- c(1:10)
event <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
time <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0)
age <- c(30, 40, 22, 25, 60, 30, 40, 22, 25, 60)

test <- data.frame(id, event, time, age, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

test.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, event)~age, data=test)
test.cox 

    Call:
    coxph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ age, data = test)

            coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z    p
    age 0.04393   1.04491  0.04151 1.058 0.29

    Likelihood ratio test=1.1  on 1 df, p=0.2937
    n= 10, number of events= 5 


# Remove patients with follow up time is zero
test_min0 <- test[test$time!=0,]
test.cox_min0 <- coxph(Surv(time, event)~age, data=test_min0)
test.cox_min0

      Call:
      coxph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ age, data = test_min0)

      coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z     p
      age 0.07575   1.07870  0.09487 0.798 0.425

      Likelihood ratio test=0.7  on 1 df, p=0.4042
      n= 7, number of events= 3
```

Comment: Could it be that people in your data who have event=1 and time=0 already had the event when follow-up started? In that case, you might consider removing them from the data since they're no longer at risk for the event.

Answer (score -1):

In survival analysis, time zero (t=0) usually represents the start of a study or the point at which individuals enter the study. Including individuals with t=0 means acknowledging that they were at risk of the event the moment they entered the study, even if the event or censoring happened immediately.

Patients with t=0 could have experienced the event of interest immediately upon entering the study. This inclusion provides a more complete picture of the risk landscape across the study population, ensuring that early events are not ignored.

Risk Set Contribution: Even individuals with very short follow-up times contribute to the risk set at t=0. This can influence the estimation of the baseline hazard function and the coefficients for covariates in the model.

When the coxph function encounters t=0, these individuals are considered at risk at the very beginning of the study. They contribute to the risk set, and if they experienced an event, to the calculation of the hazard ratio at t=0.

The presence of individuals with t=0 can affect the estimation of regression coefficients (β) because they alter the composition of the risk set at the beginning of the time scale. This can lead to differences in estimated hazard ratios and significance levels of covariates.

Excluding patients with t=0 can lead to different β coefficients because the risk set at t=0 changes, altering the baseline hazard and the relative risk estimates associated with covariates.

Understanding the clinical and statistical implications of including or excluding these individuals is crucial. For some analyses, including them provides a fuller representation of the population risk. Exclusion might be justified in other cases, particularly if t=0 represents a data entry or measurement error.

If the presence of individuals with t=0 is not due to data errors and reflects genuine immediate events or study entry criteria, their inclusion is often justified from both a methodological and clinical perspective. However, it's always important to perform sensitivity analyses (e.g., with and without these individuals) to understand the impact of such decisions on your model's outcomes.